# memcpy before send over socket increase throughput?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, memcpy

I have some data in memory that I would like to send to client through gigabit ethernet.

Server:

```
unsigned char *fbe_addr = mmap(0, img_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, mem_fd, img_buf_phys);
int bytes_sent = 0;
int total_sent = 0;
while (total_sent != img_size) {
    bytes_sent = write(conn_fd, fbe_addr + total_sent, img_size - total_sent);
    total_sent += bytes_sent;
}
```

Client:

```
int bytes_recv = 0;
int total_recv = 0;
for (; total_recv < img_size; ) {
    bytes_recv = read(sockfd, recv_buff + total_recv, img_size - total_recv);
    total_recv += bytes_recv;
}
```

By using this method, with an img_size of 65MB, I managed to get throughput around 4xx MBit/s. But if I memcpy the content starting from fbe_addr to a temporary buffer then send it out, I managed to get 5xx Mbit/s. What is the reason behind this? Also, is there any method to send the memory data out with fastest possible speed and without an additional call to memcpy?

Comment: Try writing in fixed chunks (instead of attempting to write the whole thing each time), and play with the chunk size. Start around 256 bytes.

Comment: Do you mean something like this?

    #define CHUNK_SIZE 256
    while (total_sent != img_size) {
        bytes_sent = write(conn_fd, fbe_addr + total_sent, CHUNK_SIZE);
        total_sent += bytes_sent;
    }

Do I need to modify the client side too? Besides, do you have any idea why memcpy would increase the throughput?

Comment: I trust your actual code does the appropriate thing when send()/recv() returns 0 or -1 ?

Comment: Currently my code does nothing when they return 0. When they return -1, I break the loop, print error message and terminate the program.

Comment: What if you do the memcpy but still send from the original location?  I.e. do the memcpy for no reason.  Is it fast then?

Comment: You may be experiencing one of the cache gaps. If the buffer is sufficiently small, it will be stored in cache memory instead of RAM (on the other hand, a 65MB buffer will definitely end up in RAM). Thus the accesses (R&W) are faster and the sending process must be sped up

Comment: How exactly you measure the speed? Are you measure time which takes the `while` loop in C code or whole code what you presented or even other way? For eaxmple if you measure loop without `memcpy` there can be difference caused by you don't measure IO subsystem behind possible `mmap` page fault.

Comment: I like the way it would work when bytes_recv/sent are set to -1 ;)